# Flash not loading xml in browser

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a flash movie that reads an xml file in the same directory as the .swf. This works perfectly when I just try running the .swf file, but when I add it to my website it cant seem to load the xml file. The swf and xml are in the same directory on the site and I have also tried loading the xml from a url like this: test.load('http://www.mysite.com/flash/doors.xml'); 
But this wouldnt work either :( any ideas? I'm using Actionscript 2.Thanks.

```
var test:XML = new XML();
test.ignoreWhite = true;
test.load('doors.xml');
test.onLoad = function(success:Boolean){
if(success){
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just retaged the post to reflect that is an AS2 related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi maybe you have problems with security, try adding line before loading

```
System.security.allowDomain("http://www.mysite.com");
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please note: In SDK 4.6 it's just Security.allowDomain(...) and not System.security.allowDomain(...)

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is some security issue involved with you`r problem. If you want to avoid configurating security you can try this:

```
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("config.xml");
        var url:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        this.loadEvent = loadEvent;
        req.digest
        url.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadConfig);
        url.load(req);



    private function loadConfig(e:Event):void
    {
        var ldr:URLLoader = e.currentTarget as URLLoader;
        var config:XML = new XML(ldr.data);
        .....
```

}

Comment: Hi, the question refers to ActionScript 2. You have provided an answer in ActionScript 3.