# SWF file not loading content from XML when uploaded to site

Tags: xml, wordpress, flash, swfobject

I have a SWF file which is an e-learning game that I would like to upload to a website.

The game works fine when opened in Flash locally from the desktop, however when uploaded to the site is does not load the text content from its accompanying XML file

The folder that contains the SWF file contains the following files:

- engine.swf
- game.xml
- index.html
- Include > swfobject.js

The game has a separate XML file so that the text content can be easily changed. Locally this works as it should. However this does not work when uploaded to the website.

When live on the site, the game works but it does not pull the content from the XML file - it just says "undefined".

The site is using Wordpress and I have installed the Anywhere Flash Embed plugin and placed the  object on the page using shortcode.

From researching other threads It seems that it may not be a pathing issue as the XML file is in the same file as the SWF file.

I believe it could be a security issue - I saw one [SOLVED thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782781/flash-not-loading-xml-in-browser?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) where the following had been added:

```
System.security.allowDomain("http://www.example.com");
```

Is there anyway I can add this permission without editing the SWF file?

(I tried decompiling the Flash file but when I openened the resulting FLA file in animator I got a lot of error messages about it being action script 1 and having to change things to action script 3)

Any advise at all greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the XML is loaded with a relative path the XML file should be in the folder the HTML page resides in, not the .swf file. So if you are using some SEO friendly URLs in your wordpress you might need to move your XML file. It is fairly easy to detect though - just open the developer console (F12 in chrome and firefox), goto Network, refresh your page and see where the game tries to load the XML from.

Comment: Not a programming issue. You're trying to put someone's else work (also, very old work) on your site, there's no helping if there are problems.

Comment: Thanks Philharmon - I will try that... @Organis I'm not sure what you mean - It's not my site and the game belongs to the organisation that owns the website (you are right about one thing though - it is very old).

Comment: Thanks @Philarmon - that worked (I can't seem to mark as solved or upvote answer though - sure I'll figure it out)

Comment: Hi @Philharmon - Although this was working initially - This has since caused a permissions issue (can't access the page that the game is embedded on - 403 error) which I believe is due to the fact that the folder containing the XML file in my root directory has the same name as the slug of may page - Do you know if there a way around this? Cheers

Comment: For anyones reference I found a way of achieving this by adding an exception to the htaccess file